# Get product-grid.liquid file code back

Tags: shopify

Hello I am using shopify and `Envy theme`. Bymistake i lost my

> product-grid.liquid

file code. How can i get it back ? please help-

Comment: contact with team support...

Comment: Did you delete the file completely, or, did you just erase its content?